# what is the meaning of defective duty?

Tags: bhagavad-gita

[source](https://bhagavadgita.io/chapter/3/verse/35/)

Chapter  3  verse 35

> śhreyān swa-dharmo viguṇaḥ para-dharmāt sv-anuṣhṭhitāt
> swa-dharme nidhanaṁ śhreyaḥ para-dharmo bhayāvahaḥ

Meaning:One's own duty [Customary or scripturally ordained observances of different castes and sects.], though defective, is superior to another's duty well-performed. Death is better while engaged in one's own duty; another's duty is fraught with fear.

Im not getting  the exact meaning of this verse

**My confusion**: Suppose  there   are two  person  X and Y.   X duty  is do crime  and Y   duty  is to do  noble work  but  Y  is born in criminal family and X is born in saint family.

If  X duty  is do  crime  but unfortunately X is  born in saint/royal  family.

**My  question**  Does X  should be transform  into criminal   because  X duty is to do  crime.

Similary  same case for Y

I think  this  verse  is   mean to says:

> If a man  is born  to become terrorist but  at present he is sadhu/saints.I mean  he should  give  up spiritual practice  and become  a  terrorist because his  duty  is  to do crime

Comment: For understanding the verse you need to understand the concept of Varna Dharma. When war is initiated a Kshatriya's Dharma is to fight it till his last .. he can not shy away from it by making excuses. That is what Sri Krishna was trying to make Arjuna understand.

Comment: Dhr in Dharma  means to uphold, sustain. Hence dharma is the law  (code of conduct, morality ,civil law) that sustains the social order . Hence sva-dharma is ones own role and responsibility towards their family and society in one's  context. (Any unlawful crime or terrorism , detrimental to the society can never be any ones svadharma).

Comment: (meaning of viguna can be taken as low quality or imperfection).Forsaking ones own responsibility towards family, social, religious commitments, anyone, simply for their own liking,interest choses to pursue para dharma(bhaya-āvahaḥ,  fraught with fear , as it is unnatural to their context),  with a high quality, ..Gita says it is better(shreyaha) option  to forfeit ones liking and pursue svadharma even with low quality(viguna) and fulfill the responsibilities.
        (In my understanding)